# Copy data using data factory from web socket secure link

Tags: azure, websocket, azure-data-factory

I have a URl like this : wss://**** and i have a token for this URL. I need to copy files from this location using data factory.

I could not find any activity which could be used for this and how i create linked service for the connection. I tried using Web activity but it allows only HTTP or HTTPS.

Any leads would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Azure Data Factory doesn't support web socket secure link by now. This is all [connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview) that Azure Data Factory supports. And there is no connector for web socket secure link.

Comment: fair enough..can you suggest any other method which could be used for retrieving data from a web socket secure link using Azure?